# Showing dependence of two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

With two random variables, A and B=(2C-1)A, for A~N(0,a), C~Bernoulli(1/2), and A and C are independent.

In previous parts I showed P(A < x)=P(B < x), Cov(A,B)=0, |A|=|B| and A+B is not normally distributed.

And now I want to show A and B are dependent. I tried to show P(B|A) = P(B) is not true. But it doesn't do magic. IS there any other approach? or Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are independent. Hence $|A|$ and $|B|$ are independent. But $|A| = |B|$. If $|A|$ is independent of $|A|$ then $|A|$ should be constant, but it's not our case. We got the contradiction.